# Laravel $request with variable returns null

Tags: laravel, request

I am writing an update methoda for my api. I  neede to update  requested fields. 
 So ı am trying to get only requested fields and update them. However, the code below returns me null even thoug I cast $fill to string.

```
        foreach ($fillableFields as $fill){
            $customerId->$fill = $request->get("$fill") ;
```

**edit- 1**

My code is like below ;

```
  $fillableFields = array('lastname','firstname');
```

when I dd($fill) it returns me null .

Comment: Can you show us the output of `$fillableFields`, `$customerId` et `$request` please ?

Comment: Just updated my question

Comment: And how is defined $customerId ?

Comment: customerId = Customer::find($id);

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the `save()` method to update your object :

```
   foreach ($fillableFields as $fill){
        $customerId->$fill = $request->get($fill);
        $customerId->save();
   }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your interest , it was because of postman and laravel . In postman i was using form-data  instead of x-www-form-urlencoded so when i switch it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be.

```
public function yourMethod(Request $request)
{
    try {
        foreach ($fillableFields as $fill){
          $customerId->$fill = $request->get($fill) ;
        }

        }

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and still it didn't work. It does not update my field

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get request parameters is provided at laravel's official documentation as below.

You can get request parameter based on your specific need.

By using below statment you can get only those perameter you have specified in only attribute as array eg : username, password.

```
$input = $request->only(['username', 'password']);
```

If you wantto get all fields excluding particular field than you can define as below with except parameter. eg: by using below it will allow to get all the fields except credit_card.

```
$input = $request->except('credit_card');
```

For more information on request parameter please refer official doc url : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests